Artifactory Build search page new Default after update
We upgraded our self-hosted OSS Artifactory instance from 7.39.4 to 7.49.10. After doing so, we noticed that on the Builds search/list screen, the filter defaults with a Created After date of 2024-01-01, presumably just the first of the current year. Removing the filter does not allow for a full listing of the available Builds. It appears that a filter criteria must be entered to get results (at least via the regular UI). The previous version did not have this default filter.
Does anyone know if this is a configurable option or if different versions do or do not have this default?
I attempted to look under Repository Layouts and was unable to see a way to modify this search behavior.

This was done as part of an improvement JIRA to Improve Builds Page Loading Time.
The default filter will show the builds from the last 3 months.
